# How to add an Internet Gateway to a VPC using AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am trying to produce the correct CDK scripts (TypeScript) to create an environment with a Lambda (accessed via API Gateway) that can call an RDS (Sql Server instance).

I believe I have it mostly working, but I wanted to connect to the RDS instance from my development machine to run some queries and check on a few things.

My RDS instance is in a private subnet, and [so I believe in order to connect to](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario4) it I need to add an Internet Gateway and security group to allow access on the appropriate ports.

For the life of me I can figure out the last piece, how to add the internet gateway using CDK.

The latest script I have tried is as follows:

```
const privateSubnectConfiguration = {
  cidrMask: 26,
  name: 'private-subnet',
  subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE,
};

const publicSubnectConfiguration = {
  cidrMask: 26,
  name: 'public-subnet',
  subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC,
};

const vpc = new Vpc(this, props.generateId('vpc'), {
  maxAzs: 2,
  subnetConfiguration: [privateSubnectConfiguration, publicSubnectConfiguration],
  natGateways: 1,
});

vpc.addGatewayEndpoint(props.generateId('internet-gateway'), {
  service: { name: "ig-service" }
})
```

Which then errors with `The Vpc Endpoint Service 'ig-service' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidServiceName;`

I see references to the [CfnInternetGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.CfnInternetGateway.html) in the docs, but just can't figure out how to attach a new one to my VPC?

Can you please help with the syntax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you cannot directly access a database in a private subnet. You have to deploy a proxy instance in your public subnet and forward the required ports to access your database.

When using CDK VPC construct, an Internet Gateway is created by default whenever you create a public subnet. The default route is also setup for the public subnet.
So you should remove `addGatewayEndpoint()` from your code, which adds a [Gateway VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) that you don't need.

You may also consider using SubnetType.ISOLATED to create a private subnet without a NAT GW, which may be redundant in your case. SubnetType.PRIVATE creates a NAT Gateway by default.

Comment: what do you mean by a proxy instance? I thought by opening up the security group I could access it?

Comment: A resource is not accessible out of its VPC if launched in a private subnet. So you can either launch your RDS DB instance in a public subnet or proxy the requests through an instance in a public subnet (similar to using a bastion host to access an instance in a private subnet).